# MongoDB Atlas - Java connection not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb atlas cluster from java, which is giving following error:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'Authentication failed.' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:179)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:299)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:130)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:54)
... 23 more
```

My atlas config:

- user: admin, password: ...
- ip whitelisted: 0.0.0.0/0 (for testing purposes)
- mongodb version: 4.0.6
- java driver: `implementation (group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.10.1')`

Java code:

```
List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<>();
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-00-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-01-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));
        seeds.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-02-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net", 27017));

        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(USER, "vehicle-data", PWD.toCharArray());

        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
        //build the connection options
        builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);//set the max wait time in (ms)
        builder.sslEnabled(true);
        MongoClientOptions opts = builder.build();

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(seeds, credential, opts);

        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("vehicle-data");
        MongoCollection<Document> segments = database.getCollection("road-segments");
        // Delete All documents from collection Using blank BasicDBObject
        segments.deleteMany(new BasicDBObject());
```

Someone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe check this out it may help https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2817

Answer (score 1):

solved it (with the help of the atlas help desk):

changed the server/node config to:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                "" +
                        "mongodb://admin:<pwd>@" +
                        "cluster0-shard-00-00-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017," +
                        "cluster0-shard-00-01-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017," +
                        "cluster0-shard-00-02-wgrdw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/vehicle-data?" +
                        "ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true" +
                        ""
        );
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("vehicle-data");
```

It works now